# Segmentaion Fault (Core Dumped) error while compiling project in MPLABX with C30 Compiler

Tags: embedded, pic, microchip, mplab

I am trying to program a Microchip pic mirocontroller. I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS. When ever I try to build my project with MPLABX IDE and C30 v3.30c compiler, after all the files have been compiled, I get,

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
make[2]: *** [dist/default/production/MYproj.X.production.hex] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/siddharth/work/MYproj.X'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/siddharth/work/MYproj.X'

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 4s)
```

I'm almost sure it is got something to do with my setup of the IDE as I have already used ubuntu and MPLABX for embedded development without any issues.

Can some one help me? any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: The problem appears to be with whatever command was executed by make *before* the fragment you have posted. You need to post the preceding log leading up to the fault. The second line means that a command executed by make failed, I would guess whatever command is responsible for the target `dist/default/production/MYproj.X.production.hex`.  The other lines are just the make files the failing one was nested in unwinding as the error is propagated upward.  Probably a question for Microchip Support rather than SO as it is not directly related to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an Internal Compiler error, a bug in the Compiler, triggered by a code sequence in your project. Typically the Compiler reports the line of code where the Segment fault has happened, along with the Compiler's source file name.

Most probably this should be fixed with the MPLAB C30_v3.31, which is available for download from the address 
http://www.microchip.com/stellent/idcplg?IdcService=SS_GET_PAGE&nodeId=2115

If not then you can try the latest XC16 Compiler, available for download from the website 
microchip.com/compilers

If the issue persists, submit a ticket to the "support.microchip.com"; along with your complete project; so that Microchip can look into this and fix the issue.